# Hibernation and fast startup don't work on windows 10 since dual boot with ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, hibernate

I recently installed ubuntu 20.04 in dual boot with windows 10 because I have a project with the xen hypervisor. But since I'm in dual boot the hibernate and fast boot don't work on windows anymore. I really need the hibernation because I have several projects on windows and I like to restore my work session quickly. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hibernate Windows and boot into another OS because hibernation does not actually shut down the PC.

Fast Startup is actually a hybrid suspend. Just like the full suspend, it does not fully shut down the PC. Fast Startup in Windows should be disabled if you are using another operating system in dual boot configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So I could put Windows in hibernation and boot into Windows. But hibernation doesn't even work when I try to do it the screen goes black and then the lock screen appears